# In Django, is it preferrable to have multiple apps with single model.py, if data model follows EAV-CR pattern? If not, what is the other way?

Tags: python, django, models, entity-attribute-value

I am building a Django project. The metadata gets stored in Django models.py. I have different apps in the single project. Each app handles it's own set of responsibilities. The data model that has been followed here is EAV-CR. I read that we can have both approaches as many apps single model and many apps many models. But my question is , in my situation what is the preferable way to do it? I am bit confused since the data model is EAV. (There only 4-5 tables in models.py). This may be a simple or stupid question, but I am really not sure how to tackle it, since it's my first time to deal with many apps in single project. Furthermore, if we prefer single model with many apps, how the communication between many apps will be done? Is there any best practice to do so? Your kind help will be really appreciated. If I am not asking question in proper way, kindly let me know I will edit it.

Comment: Different models for different apps is usually the best practice. 
Provided your apps are differentiable based on modular use cases. 

Interaction between these apps happens by importing required models in the required views. Please be more specific in what your query is

Comment: ya agree.. Does EAV data model makes any difference for single models approach or many models approach?